# Single Stored Procedure Per Table Update or Per Column Update

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Let's say i have a table (in a large enterprise application) that has about 10 columns.

I am limiting any consumer access to the table to only be possible by calling stored procedures.

When it comes to updating a record in the table, i basically have 2 options.

1. One stored procedure to update all the columns of the table (Total 1 stored procedure for table update).
2. An updating stored procedure per each specific cell of the column (Total of 10 stored procedure for table update).

Option (1) will probably cause more writes to the disk but in the same time will improve code maintainability which is important in enterprise applications. Option (2) may (or may not) cause less writes to the disk but will most likely be a nightmare to maintain.

**The Questions**

1. Which option should i go for?
2. Are there any other factors to consider regarding this issue?

Comment: Why are you limiting access to only stored procedures?

Comment: As an example that additional security at the database layer is used.
A consumer-type user will only interact with the database through a predefined stored procedures. a dev-type user will have more privileges when it comes to interacting with the database.
That and to protect from sql-injection.

Comment: That's a pretty expensive way to get security, when more affordable alternatives are available.

Comment: I have asked a question relating to alternatives like hibernate. My aim is to be able to (and learn how to) do both alternatives optimally. :)

Comment: Well, if you go with option 2, it will become a lifetime project for you.  There are many, many downsides to a "one SP per column" approach, and no upsides that I can see.  Databases are designed to work with (and query) collections of *records,* not *fields.* One SP per table (or perhaps four, corresponding to CREATE, READ, UPDATE and DELETE) is the way to go.

Comment: Create an answer containing your comment. It's more of an answer than a comment. And i meant 1 update sp per table.

Comment: SQL injection attacks have been a solved problem for decades.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. 
Depending on the database you might be able to provide granular permission levels for your users.
Stored procedures should not be used in this case as you are implementing a security measure unrelated to your functional logic.